# color change on data in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

i have been working on a project which do contain categories and item,what i want is i want to change the forecolor of the item so that other person can easily identify the item,other than this i have applied italics to the text it is working very well but how can i apply forecolor and font size .....so i need a help...

```
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRow++)
    {
        DataRow[] drCatFilter;
        // Get the dish item name for the current mapping
        drCatFilter = dsCommon.Tables[0].Select("ID = '" + dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["catmappingid"].ToString() + "'");
        // Create the dish item
        item = new MenuItem();
        item.Value = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["id"].ToString();
        item.Text = ("<i>"+dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["name"].ToString()+"</i>";

        ![As the image shows category(food,beverages etc.) and items(Dosa,beer etc) i need to change the forecolor of itemms][1]

    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ljsp.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the "Foreground" and "FontSize" property of your MenuItem?

```
    item = new MenuItem();
    item.Value = dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["id"].ToString();
    item.Text = ("<i>"+dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["name"].ToString()+"</i>";
    item.Foreground = "something"
    item.Fontsize = "something"
```

Or am I understanding your problem wrong?

Comment: it is showing an error on item.foreground and item.fontsize as system.web.UI.webcontrols.menuitems doesnot contain a definition for foreground and no extension method